# counting line per day

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

Db HIve

I'm trying to count table line each day between 8 and 9, for every day after 01-11-2020.

I would like to have data like that:
Date, count

This is the query I have tried to run and I get one line instead of a line for every single day. Could you help me with what I have done wrong?

```
SELECT to_date(timestamp) as dates, count(*) as Records
from table
where to_date(timestamp) > '2020-11-01' and HOUR(timestamp) BETWEEN 8 and 9
GROUP BY to_date(timestamp)
```

Comment: What's the result if you remove COUNT(*) and the GROUP BY? Does it make sense?

Comment: Note that `HOUR(timestamp) BETWEEN 8 and 9` goes from 8:00.00 to 9:59:59.

Answer (score 0):

1. If I remove the count(*) and group by - it's run, but it is not really what I am trying to achieve.

I need to have a count(*) for each date between 8 and 9 morning, that the query would run automatically each morning and give all the data from the 01-11-2020 until the date it's run.

2. When I run the query just with the hour (HOUR(timestamp) BETWEEN 8 and 9) it runs correctly, but not with the entire query.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you don't have data on all days during that hour period.  If you do have data for all days, you can tweak the query using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT to_date(timestamp) as dates,
       SUM(CASE WHEN HOUR(timestamp) BETWEEN 8 and 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Records
FROM table
WHERE to_date(timestamp) > '2020-11-01' and 
GROUP BY to_date(timestamp);
```